# Underscore / Backbone filtering of collection

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to filter a collection and return the new list so I can render to the page.

I have created a new function on the collection itself but try as I may I cannot get the 2nd IF statement to evaluate TRUE even though I know for sure that there is a match (static match).

I've even tried typeof to make sure that wasn't tripping things up.

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing.

```
var DisciplinesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Discipline,
filterByCategory: function(cat){
  this.each(function(item){
    var category = item.attributes.category
    console.log(category, cat)
    if ('intermediate' == cat){
      console.log('static match')
    }
    if (category == cat){
      console.log('dynamic match')
    }
  });
}
```

});

Comment: Seems to work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/tvfspxtg/1/

Comment: BTW it's a good practice to use `item.get('category')` than `item.attributes.category`

Answer (score 0):

I think my issue was the category parameter was a string with a list of potential categories separated by a space. Once I moved these items into a nested object my code was working correctly. Final code example for anyone interested:

```
  var DisciplinesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Discipline,
filterByCategory: function(cat){
  return _(this.filter(function(data) {
    return _.contains(data.get("category"), cat);        
  }));
}
```

});